# Setting up a custom Git installation

Tags: git

I'm looking to install Git in a custom location different from the default `usr/local/git/bin/git` directory that the package installer from the http://git-scm.com/ website installs to.

For example, I just tried copying the contents of `usr/local/git` to `/Users/braitsch/my-git` and updating my path variable to `/Users/braitsch/my-git/bin` and now Git's unhappy saying that it can't find some of its commands such as `git -stash`.

I also just tried setting `./git exec-path=/Users/braitsch/my-git/libexec/git-core` but that doesn't seem to be taking.

So my question is how can I setup a custom install of Git without the use of package managers or pre-built installers? I'd love to find a scenario that I could easily use on both Mac and Windows.

### Update

It looks like Git stash (and possibly other commands) will fail if you move the directory that gets installed at `usr/local/git` via the package installer to another location. How can I get around this? I'm trying to run Git from a custom location but it appears this is not possible via the builds on the http://git-scm.com site?

Comment: You did update your path to `/Users/braitsch/my-git/bin`, right? Not `/Users/braitsch/my-git/bin/git`?

Comment: I did, sorry that was a typo. Just made the fix. Everything appears to be working with this setup except git stash.. Do you happen to know, is everything Git needs contained in that `usr/local/git` directory that the package installer creates or does Git reach out to other dependencies on the file system? Thanks again.

Comment: What exact command are you typing for `git stash`? (and what the exact error message?) (because you did write `git -stash` with a '-')

Comment: If I cd into a git repository and run `git stash list` I am getting `git: 'stash' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.` What's strange is that stash works fine when I run it against an instance of git installed via the package on the git-scm site, but if I move the directory at usr/local/git anywhere outside of usr/local the command fails. Every other command I've tested appears to be working fine. Does `stash` rely on dependencies outside the core git package? Thanks again.

Comment: For the record I've also tried `git --git-dir=./git --work-tree=. stash list` but to no avail.

Comment: You are using a recent git, right? at least a 1.5.3? http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/qemu-devel/2009-04/msg01797.html

Comment: Yup, I was originally experiencing the issue with 1.7.5.4, just tried with 1.7.7 and the issue persists.

Comment: Is there any alias in place? Either for `git` itself, or for git aliases (`git config alias`)?

Comment: `git config alias` outputs `error: key does not contain a section: alias` and I don't have any alias' in my .profile that reference git.

Comment: It's really strange. I moved `usr/local/git` to `Users/braitsch/git` updated my PATH and everything works fine except for `git stash`. If I reinstall git via the package installer (re-create the /usr/local/git dir) my PATH still calls commands against the instance in my home directory but `git stash` will work again.

Comment: There must be a script with an hard path in it.

Comment: That's my assumption as well :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What works fine for me (including `git stash`) is to clone the git repository, e.g. with:

```
cd
git clone git://github.com/gitster/git.git
cd git
make
```

(I had previously installed the build dependencies with `sudo apt-get build-dep git`, which will work on a recent Debian-based distribution - otherwise if you get a build error you'll just have to install git's build dependencies with whatever mechanism you normally use.)

Then you can call this git with:

```
$ export GIT_EXEC_PATH=~/git/
$ ~/git/git --version
git version 1.7.7.rc0.72.g4b5ea
```

... or using `~/git/git --exec-path=/home/mark/git` instead of the environment variable.

You can move the built source tree to anywhere, and it still works, e.g.:

```
$ mv ~/git ~/tmp/
$ export GIT_EXEC_PATH=~/tmp/git/
$ ~/tmp/git/git --version
git version 1.7.7.rc0.72.g4b5ea
```

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for your response but unfortunately this isn't working for me. Attempts to set `--exec-path` to anything throws an error e.g. `git --exec-path=/Users/braitsch/test-dir/git` and setting the ENV variable via export GIT_EXEC_PATH appears to be ignored. It seems I can only get stash and now clone (over https) to work if and only if I leave Git in the same location where I compiled it. Am I missing something from your instructions above? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Just to expand on this, after moving the directory of compiled code requests to `git clone` and `git fetch` fail over https with `fatal: Unable to find remote helper for 'https'` I believe because moving the directory breaks the path to libcurl.

Comment: Thanks Mark, I did finally get this working after multiple attempts. I'm still unable to set the GIT_EXEC_PATH however the compiled code does appear to be portable between machines and around my file system which is exactly what I am after. Thanks again.

Comment: Setting `export GIT_EXEC_PATH=/my/path/usr/libexec/git-core` (and putting that into the active profile) worked for me. I was about give up on the idea that I could install git without a package installer but this solved the final hurdle. This is a useful thing for npm too, since that uses git.

Answer (score 2):

I would just re-build it from source. Grab a tarball from http://git-scm.com/ then build it using `./configure --prefix=/path/to/my-git/`.

**Edit**: I'm not sure off the top of my head how to make a relocatable git installation, but if you start by building it with a particular, unique, prefix, installing it, then grepping through the installed files for the prefix (ie, `grep -R my-git /path/to/my-git/`), that would likely be a good starting point.

Comment: I vote for this. If you're bypassing your package manager, best bypass it completely and do everything yourself.

Comment: Thanks guys. What I'm really trying to do is find or produce a self contained binary or package that I can also port to other machines. I'm in the process of building a Git client and am trying to avoid the scenario of forcing users to manually install Git or other dependencies to get Git running on their machine. If I compile from source won't that tie the instance I create to my specific machine?

Answer (score -2):

Use a VM (virtualbox is free) and build and use on a Linux machine. Having built your own, you can switch versions quite easily.

Hope this helps.

Comment: A VM just for a custom git installation location?

Comment: I did this, and I would say that while it itself works really well, it quickly becomes obvious that this solution is just not very usable in the long run.